# How to override the functionality of Back button when using Navigation Controller in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button, xamarin-studio

I'm working on Xamarin.iOS.When i move from one view controller to another a navigation bar is added to the view on which i just moved and a back button appears. On clicking the back button it returns me to the parent view. But i want some different functionality rather than returning to the parent view.
Can anyone help me out!

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: Are you sure that's really what you want to do? If you have the UINavigationController's back button do something other than move to the last UIViewController you will be going against the platform's expected idioms. Apple might not appreciate it. Also, why use a UINavigationController if you don't want it's primary functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by creating a custom button, and then setting that button as the back button for the view controller, such as:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIBarButtonItem backButton = new UIBarButtonItem("title", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, handleBack);

        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    }


    public void handleBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("back!");
    }
```

I hope this helps!